# Copy ResolveInfo item from ArrayList a to ArrayList b?

Tags: java, android

Aasically I'm trying to add an item from ArrayList a (allApps) to ArrayList b (myApps) but I'm getting an error.

This is what I'm trying:

```
public ArrayList myApps = new ArrayList(); 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
   for(final ResolveInfo app : allApps) {
        addApp(app);
    }
}

public void addApp(ResolveInfo app) {
    ArrayList.add(app); // ERROR: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method add(Object) from the type ArrayList
}
```

What does this error mean and how can I get I copy an item from one array to the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call add on an instance of ArrayList, not on the class itself, given your description, what you're looking for is

```
public void addApp(ResolveInfo app) {
    myApps.add(app);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add method of `ArrayList` is not static method so you can not call outside an instance of ArrayList. Declare instance first then call `add`

it should be `myApps.add(app);`

Answer (score 0):

Change you method like this:

```
public void addApp(ResolveInfo app) {
    myApps.add(app); 
}
```